# Linux changes serial port on shutdown

Tags: linux, serial-port

I have a device that connects to a serial port. It sends an "open signal" to a door when I set either rts/cts or dsrdtr on.

The problem I have is that when I turn off my linux computer, it is setting rts/cts or dsrdtr on. So the gate opens when the computer is shutdown.

Is there any way to tell linux not to touch the serial port on halt?

Thanks

Comment: There is a serial line setting which controls if those signals are automatically changed when the port is opened/closed.  Next you could consider modifying the kernel driver.  But finally you have limited control over what happens when power is lost.  For real positive-control security, you might want to consider using a microcontroller which could require sending an actual message of the "open/close the pod bay doors" variety.  (On second thought, don't use *that* as your message.)

Comment: @ChrisStratton Good morning Dr Chandra...